# Integrate discord community in my React website

Tags: reactjs, discord, astrojs

How can I integrate discord platform in my Learning management system (LMS) website so that my paid users can interact with each other on my website, I need to create different channels for different courses.
Can anyone please help.

I tried to use the widget in discord but its not working, is there any other way of doing this.

Comment: you could try discord OAuth where users can authenticate their accounts with you platform and the you can further process the new added users to add in respective channels or whatever you want